# How do I fix the beforeSave method for cakephp4?

Tags: php, database, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am following the tutorial on https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/articles-controller.html and after adding this function:

```
public function beforeSave(EventInterface $event, $entity, $options)
{
    if ($entity->isNew() && !$entity->slug) {
        $sluggedTitle = Text::slug($entity->title);
        // trim slug to maximum length defined in schema
        $entity->slug = substr($sluggedTitle, 0, 191);
    }
}
```

I am getting the error "Class "App\Model\Table\Text" not found". Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? [screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAPlf.png)

When I comment out the function, the article is able to save even though according to the tutorial, this should not be allowed as the slug column is NOT NULL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I realised that I needed to include Cake\Utility\Text.